# gcc "not inlined" warning

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

Does gcc's `inline __attribute__((__always_inline__))` generate warning, when compiler can't inline function?

Because VS does http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx:

```
If the compiler cannot inline a function declared with __forceinline, 
it generates a level 1 warning.
```

Comment: I added that flag - but nothing happens. It warns only when it can't inline? Can I read somewhere about it?

Comment: You can test it by taking the address of the function to prevent it from being inlined and then you should see a warning,

Comment: I think this is an answer.

Comment: Comments now converted to answer below.

Comment: Please post a test case. It may be simply that GCC is inlining the call and MSVC is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `-Winline` to get warnings about non-inlined functions.

If you want to verify this you can try taking the address of an inline function (which prevents it from being inlined) and then you should see a warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline __attribute__ ((always_inline)) int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", add(21, 21));
    printf("%p\n", add);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I've been trying to produce a warning with the above code and other examples without success - it seems that the behaviour of current versions of gcc and clang may have changed in this area. I'll delete this answer if I can't code up with a better example that generates a warning.

Comment: Some more detail might be necessary. I can't produce the warning just by following these instructions. Attempting to recurse does does produce a warning, but it doesn't depend on passing `-Winline`.

Comment: Here, working example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d83ed9ae369590ce . You can get warning with always_inline, only if you use virtual functions, or another indirect calls (which can not be deducted to plain call). Simple `inline`, from another hand - is just compiler hint indeed.

Comment: Cool - I think it was much easier to get this warning with older versions of gcc, even for C code. Feel free to edit your code into my answer if you like.